# Heroku build gets stuck at Building Source for Simple Python Flask App

Tags: python, heroku, flask

The app stopped responding with error H20. 
I tried the following to make it work

1. Restart Dynos (failed): it gives an error message *"Item could not be removed:
   Restart denied, cycling is disabled"*
2. Change some code and push new changes (failed): It gets stuck on **Building Source** step
3. Deleted existing and created new app (failed): It gets stuck on **Building Source** step

```
>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 38, done
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
Writing objects: 100% (38/38), 4.44 KiB | 350.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 38 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
```

Comment: My Heroku app has also just crashed with the same error... https://status.heroku.com/ states they have "Widespread Platform Issues" and have disabled dyno cycling.

Comment: it just got fixed

Comment: Same issue years after this original ask. Heroku status okay. None of my apps can be accessed or reset. Free tier, so i can't contact support. Nothing I can do?

Comment: Yup. I'm in the same boat. Seems there's currently some sort of outage. Hopefully it will be back up soon.

Answer (score 4):

Heroku is currently experiencing widespread platform issues. Affecting all services.

> We're continuing to work toward a resolution to this outage.
>
> We're aware that dynos cannot be restarted. We have disabled dyno
>   cycling (24 hour restarting of dynos) to avoid increasing impact. This
>   also prevents dynos from being restarted. At this point, if a dyno is
>   down there is not a workaround to bring it back up.
>
> We are continuing to work to bring Redis and Postgres services back
>   up.
>
> Most builds are getting stuck or timing out. We recommend against
>   trying to push new builds or any other changes that would result in
>   dyno restarting at this time, as those dynos will likely not be able
>   to start.